# How to add recipe in yocto to build curl example?

Tags: yocto

I can build the test.c without using yocto in my terminal easily. So this means
there is no problem with the test.c or the libcurl in my host machine.

However, when I build using yocto it complains that it cannot find curl/curl.h.

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| test.c:5:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
|  #include <curl/curl.h>
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

Here is my directory structure which contains my example based out of libcurl.

```
├── curlTest
│   ├── curlTest
│   │   ├── README.txt
│   │   └── test.c
│   └── curlTest.bb
```

Here is my curlTest.bb
curlTest.bb

```
SUMMARY = "Simple Hello World Application"
DESCRIPTION = "A test application to demonstrate how to create a recipe \
               by directly compiling C files with BitBake."

SECTION = "examples"
PRIORITY = "optional"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "\
   file://README.txt;md5=321180101a13e8916e6753497a4f9c82"

SRC_URI = "file://test.c \
           file://README.txt"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o testCurl test.c -lcurl
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 hello ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Here is the example of libcurl based out of the libcurl website.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};

static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

  char *ptr = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(ptr == NULL) {
    /* out of memory! */
    printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
    return 0;
  }
   mem->memory = ptr;
  memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

  return realsize;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl_handle;
  CURLcode res;

  struct MemoryStruct chunk;

  chunk.memory = malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
  chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* init the curl session */
  curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

  /* specify URL to get */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/");

  /* send all data to this function  */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

  /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

  /* some servers don't like requests that are made without a user-agent
     field, so we provide one */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

  /* get it! */
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

   /* check for errors */
  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
  }
  else {
    /*
     * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
     * bytes big and contains the remote file.
     *
     * Do something nice with it!
     */

    printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (unsigned long)chunk.size);
  }

  /* cleanup curl stuff */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

  free(chunk.memory);

  /* we're done with libcurl, so clean it up */
  curl_global_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to add a DEPENDS to curl in your recipe. (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-DEPENDS)

Comment: tried depend and now it fails - "temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/../poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.7.6.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
"

Comment: ERROR: QA Issue: This autoconf log indicates errors, it looked at host include and/or library paths while determining system capabilities.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am facing the same issues